# Flask unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'

Tags: python, flask

I tried to implement this code into flask, it's working correctly in the console but with http requests I got this obscure error:

app.py

```
@app.route('/results')
def results():

    keyword = {'keyword': request.args.get('keyword')}

    num_tweets=5

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=keyword+
        " -filter:retweets",
        result_type='recent',
        lang="en").items(num_tweets):
        raw = tweet.text
        clean = re.sub(r"(?:@\S*|#\S*|http(?=.*://)\S*)", "", raw)
        result = cool.api(clean)
        return render_template('pages/results.html')
```

My html form looks like this:

```
      <form action="/results">
      Input:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="keyword">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
```

I also tried a different method:

```
kwargs = {
            'keyword': request.form['keyword'],
        }
```

Adding `methods=['POST', 'GET']` do not fix the problem.

In the error page, the problem is in this line:

```
" -filter:retweets",
```

Comment: Python's errors are not obscure. Read the error's details, check the specified line, and you should understand what's wrong. By the way, if you expect us to help you debug your code, you should specify the whole error. Anyway, Python here is most likely telling you that `q = keyword + " -filter:retweets"` is not valid, because (according to the error), you cannot add a dict and a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you're trying to add a dictionary to a string:

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=keyword+ " -filter:retweets",
```

`keyword` is a dictionary. Because Python leans towards strong typing, the conversion to string isn't automatic like it is in some languages. Cast it to a string first:

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=str(keyword) + " -filter:retweets",
```

As the commentor mentioned, Python's error messages are usually quite clear. Make sure you really read them over, as they're often self-explanatory.

Comment: It's correct because now I have another error: ValueError: View function did not return a response.

Comment: @YoussefS. That's a separate error. Google that one, as I suspect that's a Flask specific error.